# Как создать Eventlistener на события появления логов в консоле? Или другим способом читать логи от socketListener

Tags: javascript, angular, консоль

[image: консоль]

Скриншот консоли с сайта на ангуляр. Как можно отлавливать все эти сообщения и работать с объектами от socketListener? Доступа к исходникам нет, не я разработчик.

Comment: Думаю единственный способ - подменить функцию log. Т.е. что-то типа **const original = console.log; console.log = function(...args) { if (checkIfFromSocketListerner(args)) { doSomeStuff(); } original.apply(this, args) }**

Comment: работает, спасибо. Можете оформить как обычный ответ, отмечу его как лучший